# How can I hide Chrome Dev Tools Console,Resources and other tabs with CSS or MetaTag or other items?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to hide tabs of chrome dev tools from people who are using my applications for security reason.

To be more specific, I'd like to prevent people from using Sql commands directly on my client side databases.

Is there any solution for me?

Any solution for other browsers such as Safari as appreciated too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such solution. If you have a sensitive information then do not send it to the client. Even if you just cache an information on the client side you need to validate user input on the server side.

Comment: I'm developing a single user offline application without any server. I've encryption/decryption for my sensitive data. But I can't encrypt all data because of performance considerations.